# Error happen python3.6 while using tornado in multi threading

Tags: python, tornado, python-multithreading

I just simply use the tornado application together with threading as the following code:

```
def MakeApp():
    return tornado.web.Application([(r"/websocket", EchoWebSocket), ])

def run_tornado_websocket():
    app = MakeApp()
    http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(app, ssl_options={
        "certfile": os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), "server.crt"),
        "keyfile": os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), "server_no_passwd.key"),
        })

    http_server.listen(options.port)
    tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    threads = []
    t = threading.Thread(target=run_tornado_websocket, args=())
    threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.start()
```

It works fine on python3.5.But it fails on python3.6 and the lasted tornado.It gets the error:

```
Exception in thread Thread-1:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\python3\lib\threading.py", line 916, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "D:\python3\lib\threading.py", line 864, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "D:\ssl\ws_server.py", line 49, in run_tornado_websocket
    http_server.listen(options.port)
  File "D:\python3\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 145, in listen
    self.add_sockets(sockets)
  File "D:\python3\lib\site-packages\tornado\tcpserver.py", line 159, in add_sockets
    sock, self._handle_connection)
  File "D:\python3\lib\site-packages\tornado\netutil.py", line 219, in add_accept_handler
    io_loop = IOLoop.current()
  File "D:\python3\lib\site-packages\tornado\ioloop.py", line 282, in current
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
  File "D:\python3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 694, in get_event_loop
    return get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
  File "D:\python3\lib\asyncio\events.py", line 602, in get_event_loop
% threading.current_thread().name)
RuntimeError: There is no current event loop in thread 'Thread-1'.
```

I think there are some changes in IOLOOP in python3.6.But I don't know how to fix this and really want to know the reason.

Comment: _works fine on python3.5_ -- checked on python 3.5.4 and tornado 5.0.2, same mistake. P.S. Why'd you need to start tornado in non-main thread?

Answer (score 4):

Starting in Tornado 5.0, the `asyncio` event loop is used by default. `asyncio` has some extra restrictions because starting event loops on threads other than the main thread is an uncommon pattern and is often a mistake. You must tell asyncio that you want to use an event loop in your new thread with `asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())`, or use `asyncio.set_event_loop_policy(tornado.platform.asyncio.AnyThreadEventLoopPolicy())` to disable this restriction.

Comment: If I use `AnyThreadEventLoopPolicy()` I get a `AssertionError: assert loop is None or isinstance(loop, AbstractEventLoop)` - see here https://github.com/tornadoweb/tornado/issues/2759